# Override Fotorama

Tags: magento2, javascript

I am create requirejs-config.js and write

```
let config = {
    config: {
        mixins: {
            'fotorama/fotorama' : {
                'Vendor_MOdule/js/fotorama/fotorama-mixin':true,
            }
        }
    },
}
```

How to override o_loop in lib/web/fotorama
`setOptions` method > `o_loop = opts.loop && (size > 2 || (o_fade && (!o_transition || o_transition !== 'slide')));`

I'm wanted set 
o_loop = opts.loop && (size > `1` || (o_fade && (!o_transition || o_transition !== 'slide')));
PS. Change size > 2 to size > 1.

How it should look fotorama-mixin.js?